# Printing Items From a Weaved List in a For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to write a short python script for use in a genome assembly. I have generated a long list of compressed files, that are listed alphabetically into List1 and List2.

```
List1=[R1_aa.fq.gz, R1_ab.fq.gz, R1_ac.fq.gz] 
List2=[R2_aa.fq.gz, R2_ab.fq.gz, R2_ac.fq.gz]
```

Where both lists go all the way to R1/2_bv.fq.gz The first part of my script needs to generate pe# for as many items as there are in the list. In the above examples of my List1 and List2, it would be pe1 pe2 pe3. This is easily done, and I am not having an issue in my script. Where I encounter my problem, is in the second half, where I need to generate text that says where to locate my files in the lists. For instance:

```
pe1="Path/To_File/R1.aa.fq.gz Path/To_File/R2.aa.fq.gz", pe2="Path/To_File/R1.ab.fq.gz Path/To_file/R2.ab.fq.gz, and so on.
```

Below is a portion of my script.

```
List1 = file1in.read().split('\n')
List2 = file2in.read().split('\n')
CombinedList = []
for i,j in zip(List1, List2)
     CombinedList.append([i,j])
for i in range(len(CombinedList)//2):
     print("pe"+str(i+1), file=Output)
for i in range(len(CombinedList)//2):
     print("pe"+str(i+1)+'="'f'{Path}/To_List1/'+CombinedList[i]+" "+f'{Path}/To_list2/'+CombinedList[i+1], file=Output)

exit()
```

What I am instead getting as an output is the following:

```
pe1="/Users/devonboland/Desktop/Test RGA/PU_L/PairedUnmapped_R1_split_aa.fq.gz /Users/devonboland/Desktop/Test RGA/PU_R/PairedUnmapped_R2_split_aa.fq.gz"
pe2="/Users/devonboland/Desktop/Test RGA/PU_L/PairedUnmapped_R2_split_aa.fq.gz /Users/devonboland/Desktop/Test RGA/PU_R/PairedUnmapped_R1_split_ab.fq.gz"
pe3="/Users/devonboland/Desktop/Test RGA/PU_L/PairedUnmapped_R1_split_ab.fq.gz /Users/devonboland/Desktop/Test RGA/PU_R/PairedUnmapped_R2_split_ab.fq.gz"
```

I have been at this small script for over 2 weeks now and have gotten nowhere fast, I would appreciate any help offered!

Comment: Why are you inserting `{Path}` if you don't want it there? (Or is there a different problem and this is an insignificant difference between the expected and actual output?)

Comment: Different problem than that, for the cluster I will run this on, I have to specify these long directories to locate my files for the overall job script. The only problem I am having, is trying to print the long strings where I need to print the total path to file and the file name from this list.

Comment: I still don't understand what the actual problem is. Could you please [edit] to explain why the current output is wrong and what you hope to see instead? (Maybe also explain what PE means; it looks like you just want to `zip` the lists, and the rest looks like vaguely redundant or tangential.) Why are you only iterating over the first half of the list?

Comment: Also, there are some inconsistencies here. I guess `To_List1` is really `PU_L` and `To_List2` is really `PU_R` but should these be added by hardcoding them somewhere, or are they actually part of the file names in the input lists?

Comment: Does this produce what you want? https://ideone.com/W5I2tx

Comment: Yes thank you. I am still new with Python and playing catch up during down time from the pandemic. I will try to implement the code you posted in my script and update here if it works, like I need it to.

Comment: Tripleee, yes that solved my error. It know prints what I need it too. Again thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments and some lucky guessing, this is what you seem to be looking for.

```py
List1 = ["R1_aa.fq.gz", "R1_ab.fq.gz", "R1_ac.fq.gz"]
List2 = ["R2_aa.fq.gz", "R2_ab.fq.gz", "R2_ac.fq.gz"]
 
# No need to .append, just create the list
CombinedList = list(zip(List1, List2))
 
# Apparently
Path = "/Users/devonboland/Desktop/Test RGA"

PeList = []
for i in range(len(CombinedList)):
    PeList.append(
        f'pe{str(i+1)}="{Path}/PU_L/{CombinedList[i][0]}'
        f' {Path}/PU_R/{CombinedList[i][1]}"')

print(", ".join(PeList)
```

Notice how the items of `CombinedList` are pairs of items, and the length of the list is simply the number of pairs.  Notice also how you can use braces inside an `f`-string to refer to variables, like you were already doing in some places but not in others.  And of course there's no need to `exit()` at the end of a script; Python will naturally stop executing it when it reaches the end.

... Actually there is no need to `zip` the lists into pairs, just loop over one and fetch items at the same index from the other in the same loop.

```py
for i in range(len(List1)):
    PeList.append(
        f'pe{str(i+1)}="{Path}/PU_L/{List1[i]}'
        f' {Path}/PU_R/{List2[i]}"')
```